# Get var from form id

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I was bored so I made this. But now I'm stuck..

```
var c = prompt("What is the max amount of movies/series that you can watch?");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*c + 1);
var i = 1
while(i <= c) {

var a = "<input id='someInput" + i + "' type='text'>"
document.write(a)
    i++
}


alert(rand)
alert(a)
```

### What I'd like it to do is:

- Ask how many (X) movies the user can watch
- Display (X) `<input id='someInputX' type='text'>` forms
- Get the id of the form and make it a var
- Display one of the (X) movies the user has entered

## Example:

I have to choose between `movie A` and `movie B`.
The popup asks `What is the max amount of movies/series that you can watch?`
I answer `2`
Two fields are displayed.

I fill in: `movie A` in the first textfield and `movie B` in the second.
And then the code randomly picks one and gives a popup `You should watch movie A` or `You should watch movie B`
I hope my explanation is not too weird..
I hope you can help me!
Thanks in advance,

Robin van der Noord
btw here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/robinvandernoord/kwvcus4v/

Comment: So you want to get the input's id when the form is submitted?

Comment: I think so. But with just one button (Like @Guffy suggested down here v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to pick one of the movies after the user has entered the names, so add a button that the user can click. Use `document.getElementById` to find the element that the random number picked:

```js
var c = prompt("What is the max amount of movies/series that you can watch?");

for (var i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
  document.write('<input id="someInput' + i + '" type="text">');
}

function pickMovie() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*c) + 1;
  var movie = document.getElementById('someInput' + rand).value;
  alert('You should watch ' + movie);
}

document.write('<input type="button" onclick="pickMovie()" value="Pick">');
```